# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable with + function

Tags: python

```
list1 = {'apple':'red','silver':[1,2,3,[4,[5]]]}
list1['silver'][3][0] +=7
```

`output 4+7 = 11`

so this is working but when I'm trying to do same thing for `list1['silver'][3][1] += 7` I'm having `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` error. Someone can help me with this?

Comment: `list1['silver'][3][1]` is a list `[5]`

Comment: Adding to @JohnnyMopp, you need to be clear about what you expect `+= 7` to do here. Is it supposed to increment all values in the `list` (making the result `{'apple':'red','silver':[1,2,3,[4,[12]]]}`)? Be appended to the `list` (result `{'apple':'red','silver':[1,2,3,[4,[5, 7]]]}`)? Replace the `list` with `7` (result `{'apple':'red','silver':[1,2,3,[4,7]]}`)? There's no complete answer here because you failed to provide the part of the [MCVE] that describes the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the elements you are working with are different:

```
>>> list1['silver'][3][0]
4
>>> type(list1['silver'][3][0])
<class 'int'>
>>> list1['silver'][3][1]
[5]
>>> type(list1['silver'][3][1])
<class 'list'>
```

You can add an int to an int, but you can't add an int to a list by default.

If you want to add 7 to your desired element, you should make the following instruction:

```
list1['silver'][3][1][0] += 7
```

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`list1['silver'][3][1]` is a `list`: `[5]`, while `list1['silver'][3][0]` is an `int`: `4`.

Answer (score 0):

`list2[3][1]` is a list , it's [5]
to access 5 use list2[3][1][0]
so your code becomes

```
list2[3][1][0]+=7;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, `list1['silver'][3][1]` is in `list` format. You can try this instead.

```
list1['silver'][3][1][0] += 7
```

Output: `12`

Comment: thank you so much!